# Error when connecting to SQL Server with C# in other computer, why?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When running the application on my PC where the host is, it connects normal to the database and the login system works. However, when I open the application on the other PC, on the client PC, it can not connect to the database and ends up catching an exception. What should be the problem ?

Appears without exception treatment:

> Network-specific or instance-specific error when establishing connection to SQL Sever. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Sever is configured to allow remote connections.

- I am using the SQL Server Express version
- I've already created the firewall rule for ports 1433
- I have already enabled communication over TCP / IP in SQL Server
- I have already restarted the services several times
- I already checked the connection string

Code:

```
public static void login()
{
    // loop
    bool logloop = true;

    while (logloop)
    {
        try
        {
            // SQL Server connection
            string conString = @"Data Source = DESKTOP-M6PEUKV\GAMBLEGAME; Initial Catalog = dbcon; Integrated Security = true";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

            // open con
            con.Open();

            // login 
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("login:");
            string login = Console.ReadLine();

            // pass
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("password:");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            // parameters
            SqlCommand comandosql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.logins WHERE login = @login AND password = @password", con);
            comandosql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
            comandosql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            // reader
            SqlDataReader reader = comandosql.ExecuteReader();

            // authenticate
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                logloop = false;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------|||Successful conected!|||-----------------------------");
                intro();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect! Try again.");
                comandosql.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            logloop = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to database, application will be closed");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us the error.  Also, do not store passwords as plain text - hash and salt them; and you ought not use `AddWithValue`

Comment: The error when I try to connect in other PC is: "Network-specific or instance-specific error when establishing connection to SQL Sever. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Sever is configured to allow remote connections. "

Comment: Can you ping this DESKTOP-M6PEUKV machine by alias or just by IP Address? maybe your LAN is not configured to resolve the alias. Maybe you need to "allow remote connections to this server", to reach this you can use Management Studio on your server machine and connect to you localhost and go to "Properties->Connections" of you Instance.

Comment: Yeah, the Instance already have these option checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TCP port allocated to the Windows Service DESKTOP-M6PEUKV\GAMBLEGAME is not available for the second PC to access.

This is typically;

1. The local firewall is blocking incoming TCP connections on that port (by far and away the most likely explanation). Using named instances requires one TCP port to be open and one UDP port. The UDP port is used to query SQL Server as to which TCP port the instance name is listneing on.
2. You have not configured the server to allow TCP connections to SQL Server and its operating in Named Pipes only mode.

The easiest way to diagnose this is to look up in SQL Server configuration manager which TCP port your instance is listening on, and then test that port using Microsoft PortQRY tool or the command "test-netconnection" in Powershell. Both those will help you work out whether its a firewall issue or not.

Comment: I will check the UDP ports, the TCP connections are already allowed in SQL Server. The The instance is set to listen all, I will try to use these commands to test and find out if it is a firewall problem.

Comment: Update: I tried everything that was requested, unfortunately it did not solve

Comment: A few questions, @sadpoints: What port is the GambleGame instance listening on?  Is the firewall open on that port?  Is the SQL Server Browser service running?  Do you allow UDP traffic on port 1434?

Comment: GambleGame IPAII is listening on 1433 TCP port and TCP 56056 dynamic port. Yes the port 1433 it is. Yes, SQL Server Browser are running. I already allowed the 1434 UDP Port acess in firewall.

Comment: @sadpoints did you try test-netconnection in powershell on the target PC - i.e. "test-netconnection -ComputerName DESKTOP-M6PEUKV -Port 56056" ? What did it return ?

Comment: @PhillipH Returns: 
ComputerName     : DESKTOP-M6PEUKV
RemoteAddress    : fe80::59bc:4d3e:c969:31ee%3
RemotePort       : 1433
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 2804:14d:783d:8287:5c2:d405:c9fe:7ec4
TcpTestSucceeded : True

I really dont know why cant acess from another PC